# Binary/Bisection Search to Determine Minimum Monthly Credit Card Payment Over A Year

Tags: python, bisection

I am trying to solve an online question using binary search (bisection search?) and I am uncertain where my code is wrong, my answers vary from the expected answer by a bit more than comfortable for me. I would really appreciate to know where I am off-course, as well as pointers for the future.
I am given an annual interest rate and an initial balance. I am also expected to select a small enough step so I can increment to the cent.
My code is like this:

```
startbalance = input('Balance: ')
annualInterestRate = input('annualInterestRate: ')
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
balance = startbalance
step = 0.01
lowbound = balance / 12.0
highbound = (balance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)**12) / 12.0
monthlyPayment = (lowbound + highbound) / 2.0

while (monthlyPayment - balance) >= step:

    for month in range(0, 12):
        balance -= monthlyPayment
        balance = balance + ((1 + monthlyInterestRate) * balance)

    if balance < 0:
        highbound = monthlyPayment
        balance = startbalance
    elif balance > 0:
        lowbound = monthlyPayment
        balance = startbalance

print 'Lowest Payment: ', round(monthlyPayment, 2)
```

Testing my code with the values provided in cases, I have the following:

```
With an annual interest rate of 0.2
and a balance of 320000,
My result: 29591.88 (incorrect, the answer should be 29157.09)

With an annual interest rate of 0.18
and a balance of 999999,
My result: 91484.0 (incorrect, the answer should be 90325.03)
```

I think I am just a little bit off and I would really appreciate some setting-straight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it (thanks, z0k!):

`startbalance = input('Balance: ')
annualInterestRate = input('annualInterestRate: ')
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
startbalance = balance
step = 0.01
lowbound = startbalance / 12.0
highbound = (startbalance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)**12) / 12.0
monthlyPayment = (lowbound + highbound) / 2.0

while (abs(startbalance)) >= step:
    startbalance = balance
    for month in range(0, 12):
        startbalance -= monthlyPayment
        startbalance = startbalance + ((monthlyInterestRate) * startbalance)

    if startbalance < 0:
        highbound = monthlyPayment
    if startbalance > 0:
        lowbound = monthlyPayment
    monthlyPayment = (lowbound + highbound) / 2.0

print 'Lowest Payment: ', round(monthlyPayment, 2)`